# Enable a button after a user chooses an option from each of two option groups

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a form to help users determine the data to input (option group 1) and the method of input (option group 2).

[image: Example form]

Once they have made those choices, I need to enable a button which will open the appropriate form to use for the data input.

I have tried to use WithEvents in a class module to detect when the option buttons have been clicked, assign and store the value of 1 when an option is chosen. My plan was to update a hidden label's caption on the form with the number 2 once two option buttons have been clicked. However, I'm failing to access and update the label under this plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use class modules take this approach. I made to classes `optBtn` and `optBtns`
This is the class `optBtn`

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents mOptBtn As MSForms.OptionButton
Dim mSelected As Boolean
Dim mParent As optBtns

Private Sub mOptBtn_Change()
    mSelected = True
End Sub

Property Get selected() As Boolean
    selected = mSelected
End Property

Property Set btn(nBtn As MSForms.OptionButton)
    Set mOptBtn = nBtn
End Property

Property Set parent(nParent As optBtns)
    Set mParent = nParent
End Property

Private Sub mOptBtn_Click()
    mParent.Raise
End Sub
```

This is the class `optBtns`

```
Option Explicit
Dim mOpt As Collection
Public Event Clicked()

Public Sub add(ByRef opt As optBtn)
    mOpt.add opt
End Sub

Public Sub Raise()
    RaiseEvent Clicked
End Sub

Public Function selected() As Boolean
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To mOpt.Count
        If mOpt(i).selected Then
            selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mOpt = New Collection
End Sub
```

In the userform I have

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents optGrp1 As optBtns
Private WithEvents optGrp2 As optBtns


Private Sub OptGrp1_Clicked()
    MyAction
End Sub

Private Sub OptGrp2_Clicked()
    MyAction
End Sub
Private Sub MyAction()
    Debug.Print "Event raied"
    If optGrp1.selected And optGrp2.selected Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    Else
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sngOptBtn As optBtn
    Dim i As Long

    Set optGrp1 = New optBtns
    Set optGrp2 = New optBtns

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set sngOptBtn = New optBtn
        Set sngOptBtn.btn = Controls("Optionbutton" & i)
        Set sngOptBtn.parent = optGrp1
        optGrp1.add sngOptBtn

    Next i

    For i = 4 To 5
        Set sngOptBtn = New optBtn
        Set sngOptBtn.btn = Controls("Optionbutton" & i)
        Set sngOptBtn.parent = optGrp2
        optGrp2.add sngOptBtn
    Next i

End Sub
```

The userform looks like that

[image]

Name of the option buttons are just Optionbutton1 through to Optionbutton5

Feel free to enhance the code.

Comment: perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Standard approach is to use a `for each` loop to ensure that option buttons are clicked before moving on in the subroutine for the commandbutton_click.

```
For each ctrl in userform1.controls
    if typename(ctrl) = "optionbutton" then 
        'do something
    end if
next ctrl
```

You could also assign a global variable once an option button is checked to ensure that you have both items both items marked, such as:

```
public o1 as string, o2 as string

private sub optionbutton1_click()
    o1 = "x"
end sub

private sub optionbutton2_click()
    o2 = "x"
end sub

private sub commandbutton1_click()
    if o1 = "" and o2 = "" then exit sub
    o1 = ""
    o2 = ""
    'Put in rest of your code
end sub
```

---

**Edit1:**

Example of the for each loop... this isn't a class module, but is a few lines of code to determine which frame (f1 and f2 are frames 1 and 2) is filled in.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control, f1 As Long, f2 As Long
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "OptionButton" Then
            If ctrl.Value = True Then
                If Right(ctrl.Caption, 1) = 1 Or Right(ctrl.Caption, 1) = 2 Then f1 = 1
                If Right(ctrl.Caption, 1) = 3 Or Right(ctrl.Caption, 1) = 4 Then f2 = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
    If Not f1 + f2 = 2 Then Exit Sub
    'do something
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: good idea. However, this approach could result in repetition of code, I fear.  Hence my thought of processing through a class module. Any ideas there? I'd use your approach as a last resort.

Comment: @Albert a class module could work, though you would still need to build a similar logic for 2 different scenarios, the left option buttons and the right option buttons.  it may benefit you to use a class module if you have *many* option buttons, but i would think that the standard approach (`for each` loop in your command button) would be similar logic to what would be in a class module.  your image lists 1/2/3 and 1/2 buttons, but you will be looking at actual names of 1/2/3/4/5, and you can build logic around that.

Comment: @Albert Edited to show how little additional code may be needed for the `for each` loop which precedes the other actions in the `commandbutton1_click`.  i just tested and that does work.  subjective, but it does have a "little" redundancy, however i feel it is in a way that is controlled and understandable.

Comment: @Cyril if i am not wrong, CommandButton1 is initially disabled and the request is how to enable it when any option of the two options groups is selected. thus your code (Event CommandButton1_Click  ) can not be executed. correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am  not sure if i clearly understood your request, but here is my solution
assuming option buttons naming scheme is OptionButton#X#_group#Y#

```
Option Explicit
Dim Opt_group_1 As Long
Dim Opt_group_2 As Long


Private Sub OptionsUpdated()
    CommandButton1.Enabled = (Opt_group_1 <> 0 And Opt_group_2 <> 0)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton1_group1_Click()
    Opt_group_1 = 1
    Call OptionsUpdated

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_group2_Click()
    Opt_group_2 = 1
    Call OptionsUpdated

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_group1_Click()
    Opt_group_1 = 2
    Call OptionsUpdated

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_group2_Click()
    Opt_group_2 = 2
    Call OptionsUpdated
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_group1_Click()
    Opt_group_1 = 3
    Call OptionsUpdated
End Sub
```